# Taking advantage of Xeon E5-2670 prices and need a Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, performance

I want to run a dual Xeon E5-2670 setup for my personal machine. I can't decide between the right motherboard for the system. My goal is too get as much processing power as possible for the lowest amount of money.

I'm considering:

1. Asrock Rack EP2C602 - but this is pricey
2. SuperMicro X9DRT-P LGA 2011/Dual Socket R - crazy form factor, not sure how to put it
   in a case
3. ASUS Z9PE-D8 WS Dual LGA 2011 Intel C602  - Super
   Cheap, which is    scary

Advice?

Comment: I love this idea, and have wanted to do this for a long time. Do all 3 of these motherboards have enough sata and pci-e slots? I think thats the biggest question. Also, Case/Space is more than likely going to be an issue, but I'm sure you've already got a solution in mind for that.  I remember watching a linus tech tips video about this, he ended up buying an old server motherboard. It worked great.

Comment: Well the SuperMicro board has two pci express slots, but that will work, and plenty of Sata. It doesn't have USB 3.0 which is a downside. The biggest problem is that I do not have a Case solution for it in mind, its a weird form factor. However, I can get it for $80.

Comment: The Asrock Rack doesn't seem to have USB 3.0 either, but, it has more of everything else. It seems to get great reviews - but its $300 +

Comment: Consider the  cost of building a DIY case out of wood, even if the DIY is just an under desk mount. Get creative with the case, under desk, wall mount, plexiglass, wood etc etc. It doesn't have to be fancy, just functional. Keep dust away, provide air flow.  These mobos, do they have a form factor standard you can search for cases on?

Comment: I think it came out of some kind of rack mount enclosure. I'm looking over its specs and it looks good, but, I haven't built anything with a rack mount board before.

Comment: Go on youtube and search for linus tech tips 150 server build

Comment: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182944R

Comment: Great video! Thank you! I'm up against some of the same issues he's talking about. But, I think I can get it done. Just got to get the right board

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45775/discussion-between-bigelittles-and-joseph).

Comment: Some guy made a couple of popular YouTube videos about these chips, and shortly thereafter, much of the remaining stock of compatible motherboards at "reasonable" prices sold out. Expect to pay at least $300 for a motherboard, and likely much more. Do not expect USB 3.0; it was too new when these boards were current. When I evaluated this a month or so ago, my reluctant conclusion was that a current motherboard and sixth gen Intel i7-6700K would be comparable in performance and quite a bit cheaper. Not to mention have a much longer shelf life.

Comment: I found the EP2C602 for 284, so i bought that